# ffmpeg giving two parameters to vcodec

Tags: android, iphone, ffmpeg, command, codec

Below is the ffmpeg command to convert still images into video with the delay of 5 seconds to each image.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/5 -i img%03d.png -vcodec libx264 out.mp4
```

This command is working fine. I just wanted to know, whether it is possible to put two parameters for *-vcodec*, as along with *libx264*, I also want to use *H264*, to make that video work even on i-phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another `-vcodec` does not make sense unless you want two different outputs. Secondly, `h264` is the name of the H.264 decoder in ffmpeg. If your build of ffmpeg supports `libx264`, then using `h264` as an encoder is simply an alias for `libx264`; otherwise ffmpeg will report `Unknown encoder 'h264'`.

Apple devices support varying H.264 profiles depending on the model. For broad compatibility simply add the following as output options:

`-profile:v baseline -level 30`

---

Note that ffmpeg usage questions are better suited for superuser.com. Stack Overflow is limited to programming discussions.